# How can I store log files to Azure storage with shell script

Tags: azure, logging, azure-marketplace

I have written a shell script to install my application in Azure MarketPlace.

I want to store installation log of my application in my storage for every installation.

How can I do it using shell script?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the question is very broad, but easiest way would be to use some SDK, like Azure Python sdk to push data to Azure storage. [Examples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/tree/master/samples/blob).

Or you can use rest api requests to push data to Azure storage without any SDK. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/rest/api/storageservices/Put-Blob?redirectedfrom=MSDN) are the docs for REST API PUT operation.